# store mysql views using functions without schema/database prefix

Tags: mysql

When I create a MySql (5.0, 5.1, 5.5) view that includes a user-defined function, the stored query text automatically includes a prefix of the database name:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'username'@'%'
VIEW dbname.NamesAndEmails
AS
SELECT `a`.`Name` AS `Name`, 
`dbname`.`formatFullEmail`(`a`.`Name`, `a`.`Email`)
FROM `MyTable` AS `a`;
```

If I then attempt to script and load this view onto a new server where the database name is not `dbname` but `account_57575_dbname` (at my hosting provider), I get the inevitable error that the function `dbname.formatFullEmail` does not exist.

I'm using `mysqldump` (to dump) and `mysql` (to re-load) -- there aren't any problems loading into a differently-named database except for these immutable prefixes.

My workaround is to `grep` the dump files to replace the database name, but am I missing the option to omit the schema prefix somewhere?

Comment: Problem is, the functions are not schema specific so the queries included need the FQN. Don't know if there is a workaround or option for this. What about naming your local schema same as the server schema?

Comment: Couldn't you say that views aren't schema-specific, too? If I use unqualified view names, the server assumes that I mean a view in the current database. And executing `SELECT functionName(parameter)` does the same thing -- assumes the current schema.